# About the sum of two sets in a topological vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

Let $X$ be a TVS and $A\subseteq X$. Then it is known that for any open set $B$ in $X$, the set $A+B$ is also open. In particular, the sum of two open sets is again open. In Rudin's book in Functional Analysis, he pointed out that $A+B$ is closed whenever $A$ is compact and $B$ is closed. Of course, it is known that if $A$ and $B$ are closed then $A+B$ may fail to be closed. Am I right to say that

**$A\times B$ is compact**

whenever $A$ is compact and $B$ is closed? Assuming that $A\times B$ is compact, then by continuity of vector addition,  it follows that the image of $A\times B$ under vector addition, which is $A+B$, is compact in $X$.  It is known that every compact subset of aHausdorff topological space is necessarily closed. The fact that TVS is always Hausdorff, the result follows.

My worry right now is whether the question I raised is true or not. Any hint or solution is very much appreciated.

juniven

Comment: What about $A = [0,1]$ and $B= \mathbb{R}$ ? Is $ A \times B$ compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

Comment: @Ahriman you should post this as solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $A$ is closed and $B$ is compact doesn't necesarily implies that $A \times B$ is compact, as shows the particular case $A = [0,1]$ and $B= \mathbb{R}$, where $A \times B$ is a non-compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Davide Giraudo completely characterized the situation where $A \times B$ is compact.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is compact *and non-empty*, and $B\subset X$, then $A\times B$ is compact if and only if so is $B$. To see that, for a direction use the fact that the product of two compacts is compact, and for the other direction, that the range by a continuous map of a compact set is compact (here the continuous map will be the projectin with respect to the second coordinate).

Comment: Is the empty set compact?  If so, then $\varnothing \times B$ can be compact when $B$ itself is not.

Comment: @GEdgar You are right, I missed this case.

Comment: For reasons such as this, some strange mathematicians want to use the convention that $\varnothing$ is not compact.  But to me that seems very strange.

Comment: I agree, as the definition with covers is perfectly fitted by $\emptyset$.

Comment: Sort of off-topic, but interesting.  Here is a consequence of compact:  every chain of nonempty closed sets has nonempty intersection.  Of course the intersection of the *empty* chain of nonempty closed sets has the whole space as its intersection.  Not a problem *unless* the whole space is itself empty...

Comment: The fact that the intersection of an empty family is the whole space is just a convenient convention. In set theory, intersection and union are defined without any reference to an ambiant space, and so only the reunion over an empty family makes sense.